# Multiplying ordered pairs

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to multiply (a,b)*(c,d)?
I was given a subring which has ordered pairs but I'm confused on how to multiply this, should I do component by component?

Comment: Surely you were given a definition of the said multiplication. Can't you find it? What's the context this comes up in?

Comment: Basically to prove that $(S, +, *)$ is a subring of $(ZxZ, +, *)$, where S has some property. So I'm not really sure, this came up on an exam, but I don't remember us ever defining how does multiplication of ordered pair work.